# Ionic page loses scroll position when data reloads

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

using ioinic 7.

i am displaying data in ion-grid.  data is multiple items in a list so the grid gets populated with multiple rows (and multiple columns per row).  the data is refreshed in the background every 30 seconds.

the problem is when scrolling to the bottom of the page and the data is refreshed the page automatically scrolls back to the top.  I'd like for this not to happen as its very annoying.

is there a way to stop the scroll to the top?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with some *ngIf or *ngFor, you empty the DOM of your page during the refresh.
Try to not change the height of your page during the refresh.

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ? If yes, please consider accepting it or upvoting. Thank you